# SQL - LEFT OUTER JOIN ON BETWEEN RANGE

Tags: sql, left-join, between

I have 4 tables that I need to join in order to find the correct AccountGroup for each AccountID.

The problem is when I try to use "between" in my join, and I get wrong AccountGroup reference.

I have following tables:

Table: Accounts

| AccountID | AccountDesc |
| --- | --- |
| 500050 | Test |

Table: AccountDesc

| AccountFromID | AccountToID | AccountGroup |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 500050 | 500050 | OtherCost |

Table: AccountExtended

| AccountID |
| --- |
| 500050 |
| 500050_Seller |
| 500050_Purchaser |

Table: AccountExtendedDesc

| AccountID | AccountGrp1ID | AccountGrp2ID | AccountGroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 500050 | 500050_Seller | 500050_A | CostOfSeller |
| 500050 | 500050_Purchaser | 500050_A | CostOfSeller |

The issue is with my query that it returns, I get wrong AccountGroup for 500050, it return both GroupDescriptions for OtherCost and CostOfSeller.

Table: Result (wrong)

| AccountID | AccountDesc |
| --- | --- |
| 500050 | CostOfSeller |
| 500050 | OtherCost |
| 500050_Seller | CostOfSeller |
| 500050_Purchaser | CostOfSeller |

I only want

| AccountID | AccountDesc |
| --- | --- |
| 500050 | OtherCost |
| 500050_Seller | CostOfSeller |
| 500050_Purchaser | CostOfSeller |

My query

```
SELECT AE.AccountID, isnull(A.AccountGroup, Ad.AccountGroup) as AccountGroup FROM 
(
SELECT 
AE.AccountID,
Aed.AccountGroup

FROM Accounts A
RIGHT OUTER JOIN AccountExtended AE on left(AE.AccountID,6)=A.AccountID
LEFT OUTER JOIN AccountExtendedDesc Aed on Aed.AccGrp1ID= A.AccountID
) A

LEFT OUTER JOIN AccountDesc Ad on A.AccountID between Ad.AccountFromID and Ad.AccountToID
```

Comment: What SQL version are you using?

Comment: I'm using V. 2017

Comment: A.ItemID does not exist in A subquery, also there is no such column in your tables

Comment: Updated, it should be AccountID. Just a wrong typing from my side.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the relationships between each of the tables. My code below assumes that anything in the `AccountExtendedDesc` table will essentially override anything in the `AccountDesc` table. I've ignored the `Accounts` table as I'm not at all sure it's needed.

```
SELECT
    ae.AccountID,
    isnull(aed.AccountGroup, ad.AccountGroup) as AccountGroup
FROM
    AccountExtended ae
    LEFT JOIN AccountDesc ad ON
        ae.AccountID between ad.AccountFromID AND ad.AccountToID
    LEFT JOIN AccountExtendedDesc aed ON
        aed.AccountGrp1ID = ae.AccountID
```

Answer (score -1):

below query gives result you need.

```
SELECT A.AccountID, isnull(A.AccountGroup, Ad.AccountGroup) as AccountGroup FROM 
(SELECT 
AE.AccountID,
Aed.AccountGroup

FROM Accounts A
RIGHT OUTER JOIN AccountExtended AE on left(AE.AccountID,6)=A.AccountID
LEFT OUTER JOIN AccountExtendedDesc Aed on Aed.AccountGrp1ID= AE.AccountID
) A
LEFT OUTER JOIN AccountDesc Ad on A.AccountID between Ad.AccountFromID and Ad.AccountToID
```

Comment: I still get 500050 with both CostOfSeller & Other Cost. The last outer join with between messes it up.